# Memory problem with EGOPhotoViewer

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, ipad

I use [EGOPhotoView](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer) for my image local gallery. The number of images is 152 and their resolution is 1400x950px.
I have problems with the memory of my device! Memory does not get released. I display one image 45mb + next 55mb + next 72mb.....and over 130mb the app crashes.
In this code I have added images:

```
NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (Picture *picture in [self fetchedResultsController].fetchedObjects) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", picture.imgName]];
        MyPhoto *photo = [[MyPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:nil name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@", picture.friendlyName, picture.type, picture.date] image:img painter:(Painter *)picture.painter];
        [photos addObject:photo];
        [photo release];

}
        MyPhotoSource *source = [[MyPhotoSource alloc] initWithPhotos:[NSArray arrayWithArray:photos]];
        EGOPhotoViewController *photoController = [[EGOPhotoViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:source];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:photoController];
        navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
        [navController release];
        [photoController release];
        [source release]; 
    [photos release];
```

I use EGOPhotoViewer as a modalView.
What could be the problem I'm having?

Comment: Edited for code formatting. It takes something to get used to how SO renders code snippets, but it's worth making sure your question is good and readable. Helps get good answers! Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're explicitly releasing the instances of `UIImage`, the photos array that you're using still has a reference to them. This means that the images aren't being released from memory as it appears you're expecting.

I'm not familiar with `EGOPhotoViewer`, unfortunately. Is there a way you can lazy load the images? There are probably other options such as reducing the size of the images, but that's dependent upon what your requirements are.